# How do i check whether the jvm options/arguments i specified got applied or not?

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am configuring JVM options/args through .conf file in springboot. eg: JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx250m -Xms2048m" be the content of .conf file.

i am running the jar using java -jar in terminal. 
now i want to check whether the JAVA_OPTS got applied to the springboot app or not. how to check that.

Also is there any other way to configure and check whether jvmoptions are applied or not.

Also I came across bootrun{}, how to check whether jvm configured via bootrun got applied or not.

Note(It will be better if i can print and check the values and I do not want to pass it directly as a commandline argument.)

i am using intellij,gradle to pack the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried visualVM, its free and powerful tool to track the java performance application, it'll show you how much your JVM committed from the physical memory, also the total memory of the application that the current JVM running, and some features:

Provide a CPU profiling.
Provide all info about Threads.
Provide the JVM Heap and the memory states.
Provide Info about the GC activities.
Its come with the JDK package, so you don't have to install it

Tutorial on how to use VisualVM : https://dzone.com/articles/all-about-visualvm